# Livewire property is null when value updated through php

Tags: javascript, php, laravel, laravel-livewire

I have a very simple livewire component

```
class Test extends Component
{

    public $test = "test";

    public function submit()
    {
        dd($this->test);
    }

    public function render()
    {
        return view('livewire.test');
    }
}
```

and view

```
<div>
    <form wire:submit.prevent="submit" method="post">
        <input type="text" wire:model="test" id="test">
        <button type="button" id="ok">ok</button>
        <button type="submit">submit</button>
    </form>
    <script>
        const button = document.getElementById('ok');
        button.addEventListener('click', function() {
            const input = document.getElementById('test');
            input.value = "Test";
        });
    </script>
</div>
```

I simplified the code for illustrative purposes to show that JavaScript changes a value.

When I click `ok` what changes the value from `test` to `Test` and then `submit`, I get `test` shown instead of `Test`.

I except to see `Test`. What am I doing wrong?

It seems that the Livewire Component is not recognising the change from the Javascript code, as the following function doesn't fire either:

```
public function updatedTest()
{
   dd("Fired");
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What @Peppermingtology said isn't *entirely* true. He is right that it is not the *preferred* way of handling Livewire, but sometimes you can't escape it.

You can indeed use AlpineJS and that will solve your issue, but you can also cast a normal `change` event. Your Livewire variable isn't updating because Livewire has not detected any change. That's because programattically updated inputs don't trigger any event by default to prevent infinite event loops.

If you simply add an event, it should also work:

```js
const input = document.getElementById('test');
input.value = "Test";
let event = new Event('change', {bubbles: true});
input.dispatchEvent(event);
```

Comment: I wanted to add that if the `change` event still doesn't update your variable, it might be because Livewire has made some changes, and now strictly listens to `change` only on `wire:model.lazy` and uses `input` for `wire:model`.

Answer (score 1):

You can't manipulate properties in that manner with Livewire. The preferred way is to use the AlpineJS [`entangle`](https://laravel-livewire.com/docs/2.x/alpine-js#sharing-state) method which specifically caters for sharing state between Livewire and your client.

That being said, you can achieve what you're after without using AlpineJS. Replacing your existing JavaScript with the below should get you the result you're after.

```
<script>
    document.addEventListener('livewire:load', (evt) => {
        const button = document.getElementById('ok');
        button.addEventListener('click', function() {
            document.getElementById('test').value = @this.test = 'Test';
        });
    })
</script>
```